# I have Created A Model using XGboost library it is XGB binary classifier . I want to visualize it of print Rules

Tags: xgboost

I am running on a server so i cannot modify The system path . plot_tree , graphviz and dtreeviz doent not work . I am posting code snippet for you reference. Help me with visualize or print human readable rules.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwRr5.png)

I am running on a server so i cannot modify The system path . plot_tree , graphviz and dtreeviz doent not work .

Comment: Share your code as the text